# What's the common way to handle AJAX file uploads/preventing orphaned files?

Tags: ajax, file-upload

I'm planning to use [FineUploader.js](http://fineuploader.com/index.html) to give my users the ability to drag 'n drop images, select multiple at once, etc... and, maybe more importantly, have the image uploading while they complete the rest of a form.

I'll be using the ASP.NET MVC/.NET 4.5/C# platform for this project.

What if the user don't complete the form? If they actually hit a cancel button I could probably fire a command to delete the images that have already uploaded. What about if they simply close the browser?

How to prevent files from being uploaded, but not used?

Comment: Chad, did you manage to come up with a solution to this problem?